# Is there something needs to be done in external website to configure for AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have https public facing website hosted on linodes web hosting company. I created Cloudfront distribution for this website in my AWS account but it shows no activity as if nothing happening. Is there something I need to do to my website?
If so what exactly I need to do?

Assume cloudfront url for my distrbution is abcxyz.cloudfront.net and my website is mysite.com which is https website.

Added:

By no activity I mean when I go to mysite.com, no data or logs generated in my cloudfront distribution which means content is coming from mysite.com and not from cloudfront cache. When I go to abcxyz.cloudfront.net, it shows content of mysite.com.

mysite.com is dynamic java website, html content is generated dynamically and user can interact with search feature on mysite.com. It is real estate website showing a lot of images of properties. All images  urls are dynamically generated and looks like
https: // [www.mysite.com/photos/properties/5eef42ca5366c1485ad8693c/thumb/2500-feet-4.4-residential-for-sale-DSC_0001.JPG](http://www.mysite.com/photos/properties/5eef42ca5366c1485ad8693c/thumb/2500-feet-4.4-residential-for-sale-DSC_0001.JPG)

I tried to add CNAME record (abcxyz.cloudfront.net) in CNAME DNS setting after login to Linode.com (my web hosting company) but it did not make any difference.

Its more than 2 weeks and still this cloudfront distribution has all metrics empty while mysite.com gets 2 or 3 visitors a day from around the world.

Comment: Have you updated your DNS to resolve to the cloudfront CNAME?

Comment: No. Not sure how to do that. thanks

Comment: Right this will be in your DNS provider, depending on who your DNS is with they should have instructions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decided to delete my original answer and give you a step by step of what to do based on what I just did. I created two identical web pages, called fast.html and slow.html; the only thing they do is load 9 very big images, which I got from here https://effigis.com/en/solutions/satellite-images/satellite-image-samples/, totaling 335 Megabytes. The slow.html web page will load the images from the images directory on my machine. The fast.html web page will load the images from the CloudFrond distribution, which in turn gets the images from an S3 bucket to which I upload the images. So, step by step, here it is.

1. Create an S3 bucket called cf-big-images and inside the bucket create a folder called images
2. Upload the images to the bucket. I copied them from the images folder in the root of my Apache web server with the command `aws s3 cp . s3://cf-big-images/images --recursive`
3. Go into the images folder in the S3 bucket and make them public; this is set readonly for the public.
4. In CloudFront create a distribution. You only need to fill the field "Origin Domain Name". Click the field and you will see your S3 bucket there "cf-big-images.s3.amazonaws.com"; select it. *[Note: I had this wrong on my original message]*
5. That's it. Click on "Create Distribution" and wait. It takes quite a bit.
6. Change the fast.html web page. On my slow.html page I had:

> ```
> <img src="images/Img15.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img16.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img17.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img18.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img34.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img41.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img48.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img58.jpg">
> <img src="images/Img100.tif">
> ```

On the fast.html web page I have:

> ```
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img15.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img16.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img17.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img18.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img34.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img41.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img48.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img58.jpg">
> <img src="https://d1pqzepyfmpq4.cloudfront.net/images/Img100.tif">
> ```

7. Then, clearing the cache each time, I navigated to the slow.html and to the fast.html pages to run some tests; the CloudFront appears to be significantly faster, but this was not a controlled test. Here are some pictures:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Hopefully it makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks for detail. in my case all images are less than 120kb and thumbnail images around 4k or 5k. I noticed in your screenshots there is not much difference for small images for fast and slow.

Comment: With such small images would not make a difference. I agree.

Comment: So your solution does not require changing DNS setting in Linode which is hosting mysite.com. Is this correct ?

Comment: What about dynamically generated large html pages on mysite.com? mysite.com involves adding new images and deleting removed property images on daily basis. So this means I have to manually copy and delete images on s3 daily? Is there automated solution?

Comment: Before I setup Cloudfront my impression was that Cloudfront automatically takes care of everything for a dynamic external website and all I have to do is DNS setting setup with my hosting company.

Comment: You can use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3. Take a look here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/ and see if any of these options fit your needs, but if you are only server small content I do not see n advantage; of course I don't have the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the general process should work:

1. user access the site https://example.com
2. example.com resolves to yourcdn.cloudfront.net
3. cloudfront checks the rules (there's a lot to unwrap here, but let's assume it's a
   cacheable content
4. cloudfront access your site's server on the user's behalf and stores the returned
   content
5. cloudfront then returns the response to the user

For the next user, steps 1, 2, 3 and 5 are run. Your site receives no more traffic.

Here's what you need for this setup

1. DNS [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and @.example.com pointing to yourcdn.cloudfront.net

WWW

- www is just a CNAME, game over

@

- @ is the apex domain, which is the tricky part if you're not using aws's route53
- @ only accepts A records, which you don't have for your cloudfront endpoint.
- @ if you are using Route53 aws provides you with an ALIAS CNAME, which solves this dilema
- if you are not using Route53, things get more complicated. You will have to find a way (either a hosted service or third party) that will let you point @.example.com to their IP, and redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- you could have a static nginx rule that only redirects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

  ```
  server {
      server_name example.com;
      return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }
  ```

*That won't solve it for everyone, there are a few cases where people also use a CDN distribution as shield from the internet, which is could be called a WAF (web application firewall) and is supposed to keep you nice and hidden from internet monsters and in some cases as cloudfront + aws can provide you with some additional protection, traffic filtering etc. Giving up your server's IP for the apex domain, kind of violates that approach.*

Now, you're all set for receiving traffic. And defining rules! Which is the fun part.

*To be continued*

Comment: If step 4 is skipped in later requests, how cloudfront knows content has changed and it should refresh it?

Comment: It seems if i setup aws route 53, the overall setup will be less complicated. For dns setting on linode.com, I have to enter hostname and alias for CNAME record.  I did not know what is alias and I just set it to same as hostname which is yourcdn.cloudfront.net.

Comment: its java based dynamic website with nginx as the frontend webserver. for ur info.

Comment: step 4 is skipped until the cache expires, this can be customized with rules for each content type, you can set css files to cache for 365 days and html files (your dynamic pages) to be cached for 30 minutes, for example

Comment: yes, route53 is a much easier setup, that is because the apex domain only accepts an A record, which is an IP. If linode's dns lets you setup the apex domain to an alias do your cloudfront domain, you're golden

Comment: they way you need to think about cdns is, you would cache your html pages for hours and all dynamic content like username, comments, products pricing, user notifications. All that stuff that seem more 'ephemeral' is fetched and updated from your javascript. Things that are more static, like blog posts, product description, user profiles, those would be cached for a long time

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if the hosting company gives you permission for DNS management.(if yes, then you can do that).Check your real server URL. (Or in DNS where your domain is mapped) Once you have that value, you need to try to create a Cloudfront distribution with that origin. and mapped the domain to Cloudfront url.

Or you can move to DNS management to Route 53. You have to create multiple records in route 53 records. Let me explain a bit.

1. You need to create a public hosted zone.(You will get Name server) and create Name server mapping in DNS Management (mysite.com)
2. You need to have a Mysite.com mapped to CloudFront distribution.
   Later you need to map your hosting link of the website (Basically public server) to CloudFront Origin.
3. if that's not possible you need to create one S3 bucket same as your domain and redirect all to the public URL of the real server.

Thanks

Ashish